# Using Encoding Parameters to merge TIFF Files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, gdi+, tiff

Edit: I found another example that creates the encoder params like this and I get the exact same error as befoer: "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

```
           Dim info As ImageCodecInfo = Nothing
            Dim ice As ImageCodecInfo
            For Each ice In ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()

                If ice.MimeType = "image/tiff" Then
                    info = ice

                End If

            Next ice 'use the save encoder
            Dim enc As Encoder = Encoder.SaveFlag
            Dim ep As New EncoderParameters(1)
            ep.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(enc, CLng(EncoderValue.MultiFrame))
```

ORIGINAL POST

VB.Net, Visual Studio 2012, .Net 4.5

I have been trying to write, borrow, or steal code that will merge multiple TIFF files in to a single tiff file. Every example, whether I write or get it from someplace fails on the same line with the exception, "A generic error occurred in GDI+". The line that causes the problem is DestinationImage.SaveAdd(img, imagePararms). There is just not enough to go on with that generic error message about a generic error. Has anyone experienced this?

Greg

```
Public Sub mergeTiffPages(str_DestinationPath As String, sourceFiles As String())

    Dim codec As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = Nothing

    For Each cCodec As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo In System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
        If cCodec.CodecName = "Built-in TIFF Codec" Then
            codec = cCodec
        End If
    Next

    Try

        Dim imagePararms As New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
        imagePararms.Param(0) = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, CLng(System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.MultiFrame))

        If sourceFiles.Length = 1 Then

            System.IO.File.Copy(DirectCast(sourceFiles(0), String), str_DestinationPath, True)
        ElseIf sourceFiles.Length >= 1 Then
            Dim DestinationImage As System.Drawing.Image = DirectCast(New System.Drawing.Bitmap(DirectCast(sourceFiles(0), String)), System.Drawing.Image)

            DestinationImage.Save(str_DestinationPath, codec, imagePararms)

            imagePararms.Param(0) = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, CLng(System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage))


            For i As Integer = 0 To sourceFiles.Length - 2
                Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = DirectCast(New System.Drawing.Bitmap(DirectCast(sourceFiles(i), String)), System.Drawing.Image)

                DestinationImage.SaveAdd(img, imagePararms)
                img.Dispose()
            Next

            imagePararms.Param(0) = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, CLng(System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.Flush))
            DestinationImage.SaveAdd(imagePararms)
            imagePararms.Dispose()

            DestinationImage.Dispose()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: So your goal is to end up with a multi-page tiff?  I haven't tried getting the ImageCodecInfo by CodecName, is the MimeType equal to "image/tiff"?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to pass in an array of single page tiffs and combine them in to one file. I haven't checked for 'image/tiff', but the for..each loop eventually hits on "Built-in TIFF Codec".

Comment: 'image/tiff' does not exists. All codecs begin with 'Built-in...'

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not find a solution for this code I did find code that works. JohnH a moderator at http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/ posted the code below in this thread http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/graphics-gdi/22113-create-multipage-tiff-loop.html

It works for me. I added a few lines at the top to show how I called it.

Greg

```
'Example: Combine 4 tiff images in a new file called FinishedTiff.tiff
'Dim oNewImage As Image

'oNewImage = Image.FromFile("C:\IRISScan\Week of Jan 6 no SSN_Page_1.tif")
'SaveAddTiff(oNewImage, "C:\IRISScan\FinishedTiff.tif")

'oNewImage = Image.FromFile("C:\IRISScan\Week of Jan 6 no SSN_Page_2.tif")
'SaveAddTiff(oNewImage, "C:\IRISScan\FinishedTiff.tif")

'oNewImage = Image.FromFile("C:\IRISScan\Document3_Page_1.tif")
'SaveAddTiff(oNewImage, "C:\IRISScan\FinishedTiff.tif")

'oNewImage = Image.FromFile("C:\IRISScan\Document3_Page_2.tif")
'SaveAddTiff(oNewImage, "C:\IRISScan\FinishedTiff.tif")
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Module modTiff
'

Sub SaveAddTiff(ByVal img As Image, ByVal filename As String)
    If Not IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        img.Save(filename, Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
    Else
        Dim frames As List(Of Image) = getFrames(filename)
        frames.Add(img)
        SaveMultiTiff(frames.ToArray, filename)
    End If
    img.Dispose()
End Sub

Sub SaveMultiTiff(ByVal frames() As Image, ByVal filename As String)
    Dim codec As ImageCodecInfo = getTiffCodec()
    Dim enc As Encoder = Encoder.SaveFlag
    Dim ep As New EncoderParameters(2)
    ep.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(enc, CLng(EncoderValue.MultiFrame))
    ep.Param(1) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, CLng(EncoderValue.CompressionNone))
    Dim tiff As Image = frames(0)
    tiff.Save(filename, codec, ep)
    ep.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(enc, CLng(EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage))
    For i As Integer = 1 To frames.Length - 1
        tiff.SaveAdd(frames(i), ep)
        frames(i).Dispose()
    Next
    ep.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(enc, CLng(EncoderValue.Flush))
    tiff.SaveAdd(ep)
    tiff.Dispose()
End Sub

Function getTiffCodec() As ImageCodecInfo
    For Each ice As ImageCodecInfo In ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
        If ice.MimeType = "image/tiff" Then
            Return ice
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function

Function getFrames(ByVal filename) As List(Of Image)
    Dim frames As New List(Of Image)
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(filename)
    For i As Integer = 0 To img.GetFrameCount(Imaging.FrameDimension.Page) - 1
        img.SelectActiveFrame(Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, i)
        Dim tmp As New Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmp)
        g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
        g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
        g.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
        g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(img, 0, 0)
        frames.Add(tmp)
        g.Dispose()
    Next
    img.Dispose()
    Return frames
End Function
```

End Module

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your code. It works however something goes wrong once we get past the 'SaveMultiTiff' procedure and it shrinks the page to a quarter of its original size. Do you know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
g.DrawImageUnscaled(img, 0, 0)
```

with

```
g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(img, New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height))
```

and it fixed the scaling issue where it would shrink the image to a quarter of its original size

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I guess that is an answer to the comment? (It doesn't seem to be an issue described in the original question)

Comment: Correct. I couldn't directly comment because I just made my account. Sorry, I'm new here.